# No response from invoke container for FunctionName

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-sam-cli, sam

Trying to port forward **dockerized Lambda** to my **localhost** using command:

```
$ sam local start-api --docker-network host
```

Error every time trying to access Lambda:

***No response from invoke container for FunctionName***

Tried also using **host.docker.internal** & **host.docker.local** networks with no success.

Any ideas? Workarounds?

Comment: Can you pass argument `--debug` and see is there any additional information available? Also, does it work with local Docker (without `--docker-network`)?

Comment: Nothing there, it seems to be a known open issue of SAM

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem to work, but using your host computer's IP address does...

Say your host computer's IP address is 192.168.1.111 . You can use that from your Lambda to hit your host

You can make this configurable:

template.yml:

```
...
Environment:
  Variables:
    ENDPOINT_URL: null
```

env.json:

```
{
  "Parameters":{
    "ENDPOINT_URL":"http://192.168.1.111:5000"
  }
}
```

lambda_function.py:

```
...
default_sns_endpoint = f'https://sns.{os.environ["AWS_REGION"]}.amazonaws.com'
endpoint_url = os.environ.get("ENDPOINT_URL", "") or default_endpoint

sns = boto3.client("sns", endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
...
```

start SAM:

```
sam local invoke --env-vars env.json
```